# paypal advanced checkout doesn't load form elements

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to integrate paypal advanced checkout to my website,
but I have problems with loading the custom form elements

this is my form page:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?components=buttons,hosted-fields&client-id={{env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID')}}" data-client-token="{{$client_token}}" ></script>

let orderId;

     // Displays PayPal buttons
     paypal.Buttons({
       style: {
         layout: 'horizontal'
       },
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
           return actions.order.create({
             purchase_units: [{
               amount: {
                 value: "1.00"
               }
             }]
           });
         },
         onApprove: function(data, actions) {
           return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
             window.location.href = '/success.html';
           });
         }
     }).render("#paypal-button-container");

     // If this returns false or the card fields aren't visible, see Step #1.

     if (paypal.HostedFields.isEligible()) {

       // Renders card fields
       paypal.HostedFields.render({
         // Call your server to set up the transaction
         createOrder: function () {
           return fetch('/paypal/process/', {
            method: 'post'
          }).then(function(res) {
              return res.json();
          }).then(function(orderData) {
            orderId = orderData.id;
            return orderId;
          });
         },
..........
     } else {
       // Hides card fields if the merchant isn't eligible
       document.querySelector("#card-form").style = 'display: none';
     }
```

enter where it says (// Hides card fields if the merchant isn't eligible)
I have the business account enabled and I previously generated the client token correctly

Comment: Have you activated hosted fields on the account, per the documentation? What does `paypal.HostedFields.isEligible()` return?

Comment: return false.. where i have to activate that hosted fields on my account?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can accept card payments with Advanced, you must request advanced debit and credit card processing. This is documented in [the first section of the integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/#link-enableyouraccount), with a link to do it for sandbox mode (you'll need to do it separately for live)

Comment: I already created a business account and I have completed the activation steps, where would be the link for the sandbox

Comment: The first link in that 'Enable your account' section. https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/bizsignup/entry/product/ppcp